# Can't find what XPath function this belongs to

Tags: xslt, xpath, transform

I'm currently trying to understand a XSL document I am working on and have come across this

```
<xsl:when test="(string(@hideIfHardwareIs)='')>
```

I found that in XSLT 2.0 there is fn:string(). Is the above string() the same? Meaning it will return a string version of what it finds at hideIfHwardwareIs ?

Comment: Are you working in an XSLT2 stylesheet?  If so, the answer is yes.

Comment: The standard XPath function library defines function names in a namespace, conventionally written with the prefix "fn:". In XSLT this is always the default namespace for functions, so no prefix is needed: the function can simply be written string().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. `string()` produces the string value of its argument. In this case, it and the other set of parentheses are redundant, because the comparison with `''` should automatically convert it to a string. This should be fine:

```
<xsl:when test="@hideIfHardwareIs = ''">
```

[string() function in the XPath 1.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions)